# Store Neomutt Mails in External Disk

Tags: archlinux, mutt, neomutt

I have installed Neomutt on Arch Linux using Luke Smith's Mutt-Wizard. It's working fine. I am storing all my emails in my local laptop's `~/.config/mutt/accounts` folder which is mentioned in my `.muttrc` file.

But I have thousands of emails. So I wanted to change the location of storing the mails. I intend to store them on an external hard disk. But when I write the location of external disk in my `.muttrc`, Neomutt gives me error:

> Maildir error: cannot read UIDVALIDITY.

> Error: channel joy_deep@gmx.com: near side box INBOX cannot be opened.

Is there any way to config this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out somehow. I copied the mw file to mymw file. I changed the bash script. In maildir location, I put my Nextcloud folder. Changed same for .mbsyncrc file. Now it works.

Thanks.